# How to enable (lockfree boost::atomic_flag : "no (cached)") on Solaris-10 while building Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, solaris-10

Am actually newbie to Boost library and am currently trying to build boost library on Solaris-10 platform,
The Following command am using to build boost:

> ./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=sun --with-libraries=atomic,thread,regex
>
> ./b2 variant=release address-model=64 runtime-link=shared cxxflags="-std=c++11    -m64 -xarch=sparc -mt" linkflags="-std=c++11 -m64 -xarch=sparc -mt" threading=multi toolset=sun stage

The only problem am seeing while building boost library is the following:

> - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : no  (cached)

The lockfree feature is not getting enabled.
Could any one help me in understanding like what am i missing and what i need to add to command line to enable the lookfree feature

> Boost Library Version - 1.61
>   Compiler - SolarisStudio-12.4 CC compiler
>   O.S architecture = 64bit
>
> On **RedHatLinux-6** the boost builds fine with g++ compiler with out any additional flag set via command line, also it says **lockfree boost::atomic_flag : "**yes**(cached)"**

Comment: I've tired to set the variable(**BOOST_ATOMIC_FLAG_LOCK_FREE = 1**) value to true by passing it as argument to **./b2** executable  under cxxflags="BOOST_ATOMIC_FLAG_LOCK_FREE = 1", now when am trying to build it is getting enabled i.e "lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes", but when am running a test program still it says the program is "" NOT LOCK FREE"

Comment: Humm, doing this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have C++11 compiler installed on all UNIX machines, as the Boost library mostly makes use of C++11 library API calls.